# Deep linking relaunch in Android after application exit

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

Even if I exit my application and re-open it again, it opens the last visited page instead of re-launching the app.
The previous instance is not destoyed and still remains.
I am using "getLatestReferringParams" method for deep linking.Even after killing the app this method is returning params assiocciated with link.

How to make sure that deep linking kills the instance when application is killed in android ?

```
<activity
            android:name=".SomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <meta-data android:name="some_sdk_link" android:value="SomeId" />
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="SomeActivity"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: add the AndroidManifest and the activity that handles the deep linking

Comment: Added the manifest